# Why JPQL expressions cannot navigate beyond relationship fields that are collections?

Tags: java, jpa, expression, field, jpql

[Excerpt from Java EE 7 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage004.htm):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Player p, IN (p.teams) AS t WHERE t.city = :city
```

> Expressions cannot navigate beyond (or further qualify) relationship
>   fields that are collections. In the syntax of an expression, a
>   collection-valued field is a terminal symbol. Because the teams field
>   is a collection, the WHERE clause cannot specify p.teams.city (an
>   illegal expression).

Why expressions cannot navigate beyond relationship fields that are collections?

Comment: Because that's how the language was designed.

Comment: @JBNizet So, what could be the reason of such a design decision? IOW, what could go wrong if fields could be accessible through navigation?

Comment: I didn't design the language, and I could of course miss more important reasons, but IMHO, it wouldn't make much sense: `p.teams.city` means "the city property of the teams property of p". But teams is a collection. And collections don't have any city property.

Comment: @JBNizet How could I miss that, its so atrocious. I will accept your comment as answer if you do so.

Comment: @JBNizet Looks like you have a great time with newbies ;)

Comment: IIRC, eclipselink (and/or hibernate?) does support `p.teams.city = ...` as an extension to JPA's JPQL.

Comment: @JimmyB That's interesting. Given your comment and accepted answer, how does city resolve to a particular collection element?

Comment: It doesn't. Like in SQL it resolves to a *set* of values/records, and in the end in itself it only turns into a *join* in SQL. JPQL `WHERE p.teams.city = 'xyz'` yields SQL `FROM Player p JOIN Teams t ON ... WHERE t.city = 'xyz'`. Just like `IN (p.teams) AS t` does.

Comment: @JimmyB Wonder why JPQL itself didn't implement such an extension feature.

Comment: @JBNizet I request you to share your thoughts on JimmyB's comment.

Comment: JBNizet and JimmyB: Thanks for your inputs. As a newbie, I'm trying to learn, so please bear with me.

Comment: @user1418717 have you tested it? I have. Hibernate gives the exception "org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection". Don't know about EclipseLink, but I wouldn't use that.

Comment: @JBNizet Honestly, I'm still in theory part. I have yet to practice. Thanks for confirming on Hibernate, though.

Comment: @JimmyB I suppose what you mean is mentioned in [39.5.4.3 Navigation section](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage005.htm)

Comment: @JBNizet Please answer, if possible - [Why use the term abstract schema in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880932/why-use-the-term-abstract-schema-in-jpa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't design the language, and I could of course miss more important reasons, but IMHO, it wouldn't make much sense: `p.teams.city` reads as "the `city` property of the `teams` property of `p`". But `teams` is a collection. And collections don't have any `city` property.

That's at least a good way to remember that this is not vald JPQL.

Comment: I don't think this explanation is a good one. Of course, in Java `p.teams` will be mapped to a collection. But that's really an artifact of the programming language (just like the lack of true bi-directional associations) and there's no need for a DB query language to follow the other language. - One wouldn't expect to be able to use `p.teams.size()` or `p.teams.add(...)` in JPQL.

Comment: @JimmyB I suppose, what you mean is mentioned in [39.5.4.3 Navigation section](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage005.htm)

Comment: @JimmyB there's no *need*, but familiarity helps grasping and reasoning about the new language. They **could** have used `retrieve`instead of `select`, but familiarity with SQL helps, too. I also guess that forcing the developer to use a join helps making him realize about what really happens behind the scene.